# How to modify `Text` of the parent from the children level in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I got an `app.py` file where the main class `App(Tk)` is being invoked. Within it I create three children, with two being relevant (in the middle and on the right of the image):

```
    self.active_module = main_module.MainModule(self.main)
    self.active_module.grid(column=1,row=0)
```

and

```
    self.preview = Text(self.main,state='disabled',width=50)
    self.preview.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=E)
```

The `active_module` is a `ttk.Notebook` with several `ttk.Frame` and separated as a `main_module.py` file. One of those frames got combobox with different values...

**...and the question is how to let `preview` Text be modified upon changing the combobox value?** For clarity purposes I also attach the image how it looks alike:

[image]

The relevant parts of code are as follows:

**app.py**

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        [...]

        self.active_module = main_module.MainModule(self.main)
        self.active_module.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.preview = Text(self.main,state='disabled',width=50)
        self.preview.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=E)
```

**main_module.py**

```
class MainModule(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.add(General(self),text="General")

class General(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.runtype_label = ttk.Label(self,text="Runtype:")
        self.runtype_label.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=W)
        self.runtype_combobox = ttk.Combobox(self,state="readonly",values=("1","2","3"),width=9)
        self.runtype_combobox.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=W)
        #self.runtype_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.runtype_choice)
```

Comment: You can pass a callback reference to `MainModule` and then pass this callback to `General`.

Comment: I tried to do that by passing `self.preview` through `__init__`'s and constructors but does not work

Comment: Perhaps if you update your question to show your code that didn't work and any error messages, someone can help to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't store the parent as a class variable inside your `__init__` method? `self.parent = parent`. Then other methods within the class can use the reference to the parent object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `MainModule` class and then pass this callback to `General` class.

**app.py**

```py
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main = Frame(self)
        self.main.pack()

        # pass callback to MainModule class
        self.active_module = main_module.MainModule(self.main, self.insert_text) 
        self.active_module.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.preview = Text(self.main, state='disabled', width=50)
        self.preview.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=E)

    def insert_text(self, text):
        self.preview.config(state='normal')
        self.preview.insert('end', f'{text}\n')
        self.preview.config(state='disabled')
```

**main_module.py**

```py
class MainModule(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent, callback):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # pass callback to 'General' class
        self.add(General(self, callback), text="General")

class General(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, callback):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.runtype_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Runtype:")
        self.runtype_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)
        self.runtype_combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, state="readonly", values=("1","2","3"), width=9)
        self.runtype_combobox.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)
        # call the callback whenever item is selected
        self.runtype_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda e: callback(self.runtype_combobox.get()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks good. However, the problem is somehow major because this is one of the many checkboxes that would interfere the `preview` content. For example, initial state is: `Default text`. When I click checkbox in `General` tab, the `preview` would change into: `APFD`. And when I click another one, in some other tab, it would change into: `APFD def2`. On the other hand, when I uncheck the one from `General` just `def2` would be present. I know this is more about manipulating with inserting and removing, but how these checkbox could be bound to `preview` in so many ways?

Comment: @farmaceut Such situations have never been mentioned in the question, my answer is based on provided information.  However if you understand the logic, you can modify it to suit your case.

Comment: Indeed. Forgot to mention! I have just implemented what you sent me. I am not very good with lambda nonetheless I feel how it works and will surely modify it as necessary. Thank you very much :) Now I just need to manage it to remove the text upon change